# What am I doing wrong? My Socket won't receive data send to it

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator, udp

I have a separate `C#` program which sends data to any IP-Address I specify in it. The data is encoded in a way that I can decode it again (`UTF-8`) and sent through an `UDPClient`. I've set up this program to send the data to a port on my machine which I forward to the `Android Emulator`. In my application I have a DatagramSocket set on this port, but my receive call doesn't return any data to me...

I know for sure that data is sent, when I debug the `C#` program on the send statement, I see it actually sends data away... I suspect it is something in my Socket settings, but I don't know what...

```
private void updateUDPSocket(String IpAddress, String IpPort){
    Inet4Address ownIpAddress = null;
    int ownIpPort = 0;

    /*
     *  Try to recover the correct Inet4Address & Port.
     *  Catch all possible exceptions as well.
     */
    try{
        ownIpAddress = (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getByName(IpAddress);
        ownIpPort = Integer.parseInt(IpPort);
    } catch (UnknownHostException uhe){
        uhe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Check to see if the current socket is already initialised.
    if(mUDPSocket != null){
        // If so, close & nullify it.
        mUDPSocket.close();
        mUDPSocket = null;
    }

    // Create a new socket & catch the possible exception.
    try{
        mUDPSocket = new DatagramSocket(ownIpPort, ownIpAddress);
        mUDPSocket.setSoTimeout(TIME_OUT_IN_MILLIS);
    } catch (SocketException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Log current set address & port.
    Log.d(TAG, "UDPSocket set to address:" +
        mUDPSocket.getLocalAddress() + ":" + mUDPSocket.getLocalPort());
}
```

The IP-Address I pass here is either `0.0.0.0` (in case of the emulator) or the IP-Address recovered from the `WifiManager` (in case of a mobile device).
It doesn't fail in setting the Socket, but per haps I am using the wrong address?

The only output I get from the receive method is the error message of the receive getting timed out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know now that there is nothing wrong, I've tested this on a real device now, and it will receive data on the Socket...